# Magento:Move block position

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, blocks

I want to customize cart page. I want to move the position of side blocks(discount coupon, shipping and tax and grand total) just below the cart items table.

I tried using "before" and "after" by editing catalog.xml but there was no change in their positions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use some simple CSS to fix this. The summary is currently after the cart items table so changing via xml won't change much.

```
.cart-table {
    width: 100%;
}
.cart-forms {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using a `2columns-right` template in your cart, try this one :

`app/design/frontend/{package}{theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
<checkout_cart_index>
```

If it doesn't work try this:

Go to : `app/design/frontend/{package}{theme}/template/checkout/cart.phtml` then move `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>` to  :

```
...
    </tbody>
</table>
/*Here*/
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```